# Can not execute command with root in a remote Linux host

Tags: shell, ssh

I try to migrate shell code to Python fabric code. The issue I meets is that Python can not execute command with root in a remote Linux host. Could anyone meet this issue and figure it out? I am very appreciate for your help. Thanks in advance.

```
TestHost1="host01 host02 host03"
for host in $TestHost1
do sshpass -p password ssh -T -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
                           -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@$host << EOL;
sudo su -
sed -i 's/10./172./g'/etc/hosts
EOL
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute it on this way:

```
TestHost1="host01 host02 host03"
for host in $TestHost1
do sshpass -p password ssh -T -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@$host "sudo sed -i 's/10./172./g'/etc/hosts"

done
```

Comment: Thanks Romeo. For security policy in my company hosts, admin user can't directly run sudo command except "sudo su - root" . In that way, I have to su to root before I run any command which needs root permission.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `sudo` to be able to prompt for a password you need to give it a tty device (a *pseudo-tty*). `ssh` will usually create the pseudo-tty device on the remote end if its input is also from a terminal. However, in this case it isn't - you're using a *heredoc* (the `<<` bit).

To copy your style, you need to add the `RequestTTY` option to `ssh`, also available implemented as `-t`. Confusingly you have explicitly *disabled* pseudo-tty allocation with your `-T` flag, so you need to replace that:

```
TestHost1="host01 host02 host03"
for host in $TestHost1
do sshpass -p password ssh -t -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@$host << EOL;
sudo su -
sed -i 's/10./172./g' /etc/hosts
EOL
done
```

However, you might want to review your replacement match `10.`; as it stands that matches the two characters `10` plus any one character (the `.` is a wildcard), multiple times per line. Perhaps it should be `10\.` (match three literal characters) or even `^10\.` (match three literal characters at the start of the line). Here I've assumed you meant three literal characters `10.` at the start of the line:

```
TestHost1="host01 host02 host03"
for host in $TestHost1
do sshpass -p password ssh -t -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@$host sudo sed -i.bak 's/^10\./172./' /etc/hosts
done
```

Comment: hi Roaima, thanks for your reply. Precisely, what I want to ask may more like this URL:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113706/running-fabric-scripts-as-root